# Is there a way to enforce/test Powershell 1.0 compatibility on a machine with a higher version installed?

Tags: powershell, version, compatibility, powershell-1.0

I have a powerscript that when I distribute it I would like to ensure works even if powershell 1.0 is the only version installed. While there is a way to [run other versions of PS side-by-side](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2011/12/20/powershell-2-and-3-side-by-side.aspx), there doesn't seem to be so for 1.0.

Running ...\powershell\1.0\powershell or

```
powershell -version 1.0
```

both result in the $PSVersionTable.PSVersion command still working in my development environment (where it should fail as the $PSVersionTable doesn't exist in 1.0).

Is there another way to get a powershell 1.0 sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

As you need PowerShell V 1.0 on your network, that is because you still have Windows XP or Windows Server W2K3 working on your network.

The think I do is to install PowerShell V1.0 on the top of an XP VM.